# Salesforce standard translation is not working for custom development?

Tags: translation, localization

Here I set the user local and language as italian

[image: Here I set the user local and language as italian]

The entire page is translated except custom components (lwc,aura).

[image: The entire page is translated except custom components(lwc,aura).]

LWC

```
<lightning-card  title="Hello">
    <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
  
    <p >hi..! how are you...(this is lwc)</p>

</lightning-card>
```

AURA

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"  access="global">
    <lightning:card footer="Card Footer" title="Hello">
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <lightning:button label="New"/>
        </aura:set>
        <p >
            Hi..how are you? (this is aura)
        </p>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't work for custom components as Salesforce does not translate stuff dynamically. What you have to do is use Custom Labels and the Translation Workbench (you can find both in Setup).